# F# implementing interfaces with different template parameters

Tags: f#

Having this code:

```
type Point2D(x, y) =
    member this.X with get() = x
    member this.Y with get() = y

    interface System.IEquatable<Point2D> with
        member x.Equals point =
            x.X = point.X
            && x.Y = point.Y

type Point3D(x, y, z) =
    inherit Point2D(x, y)

    member this.Z with get() = z

    interface System.IEquatable<Point3D> with
        member x.Equals point =
            (x :> System.IEquatable<Point2D>).Equals point
            && x.Z = point.Z
```

http://take.ms/rjWlJ

I have compile-time. F# is not allow implement the same interface with different template parameter. But I want to implement strongly-typed equals in derived type. So what should I do with it?

Comment: As F# hints, *This is not permitted in this version of F#*, in the latest version of F#. Do you intend to use that from C#, or is it only targeted at F#?

Answer (score 3):

No-can-do. Which is a slightly sorry state of affairs, since F# can consume a type with such a  design perfectly well when it comes from a different CLR language.

The explanation I heard was that having such a feature was not deemed important, partially because having such a class/interface-heavy design was not considered idiomatic (which I agree with).

So one option you have is implementing those types in C#.

Another more idiomatic way would be to implement them as records:

```
type Point2D = { x: float; y: float }

type Point3D = { x: float; y: float; z: float }
    with 
        static member FromPoint2D (p: Point2D) = ...
        member this.ToPoint2D () = ...
```

Perhaps add a module with a function for comparing 2d and 3d that will encapsulate the conversion for you.

Comment: I think this is exactly the kind of harmless feature that could well get implemented now that the language is open to pull requests.

Answer (score 2):

As the compiler error explains, this isn't supported so the best solution is probably to avoid inheritance in this case and add a member to convert to a 2d point:

```
type Point3D(x, y, z) =
        member this.X with get() = x
        member this.Y with get() = y
        member this.Z with get() = z

        member this.As2D = new Point2D(this.X, this.Y)

        interface System.IEquatable<Point3D> with
            member x.Equals point =
                x.X = point.X && x.Y = point.Y && x.Z = point.Z
```